# Japanese movie with alien acrobats with horrible Joker faces

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

There's a Japanese movie that terrified me as a child.

All I can remember is there were aliens that were acrobats and they wore white leotards and wore masks, and when they took off their masks, they revealed horrible Joker-like faces. Very wide grotesque mouths.

My sister just reminded me of this movie, and now I will have nightmares tonight, 50 some years later. She seems to remember that a white blob-like creature was also involved. I only remember being terrified.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this a live-action movie or animated?

Answer (score 2):

It might be one of the [Starman](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Giant) movies. There were several made ([*Atomic Rulers of the World*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_Rulers_of_the_World), [*Invaders from Space*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invaders_from_Space), [*Attack from Space*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_from_Space), and [*Evil Brain from Outer Space*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_Brain_from_Outer_Space) are the ones I can think of) and all featured a lot of acrobatic fights.

Answer (score 2):

Wait a second – I think it's the Evil Brain from Outer Space. I just watched it in fast-forward (it's free on YouTube). I think both my sister and I are conflating 2 different types of scary faces. There's a lady at the circus who has a very joker like face. Then there's these devilish acrobatic aliens whose long fingers twitch in  a very frightening way. Funny, both of us seem to remember that the kids are at the circus in the acrobats are very very good (because they are aliens) and then, at a certain point they take off their masks to reveal the joker face, the fangs, the whole bit.  Maybe my sister and I had a collective Mandela moment, conflating and misremembering scenes.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. As a self-answer, you won't be able to complete the process until 48 hours after your question was asked, although clicking earlier will just tell you how much time is left.

Comment: You can improve your answer by providing a link to the film (say on Wikipedia or IMDB), a quoted plot summary, screenshots, and/or trailer links.

Answer (score -1):

Well, through exhaustive research I figured out that the liquefying-blob movie was "The H Man", so my sister must have conflated scenes from two different movies (H man blob people movie and terrifying Joker-faced acrobats) from late 1950s early 1960s Japanese sci-fi films.

The acrobatic aliens with terrifying Joker faces movie was in black-and-white; I watched it on UHF TV probably anywhere from 1968 to 1971. I would guess the movie with the acrobats dates from 1957 to 1964. It's fairly likely that it was a Starman or Starman-like movie but I fast forwarded through the Starman movies (I think there's only four in total) and I did not see the terrifying scene.

Comment: Hi!  You've now posted the answer, so you should probably edit this realization into either the question or the correct answer.  "It's not {this}" isn't really an answer.